# Jquery keep link hidden until all dropdowns have been changed

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where I must hide a link until all drop downs have changes from their default state of 'select...' The link should only show after all three of the drop downs no longer contain the select, it also should hide the link if the default select... Is reselected.

Here is a fiddle showing you what I have that works for only the first selection but does not work if select is chosen once again, is also ignore the other drop down menus.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".BuyButton").hide()
    $('.Option').change(function() {
        var str = $('.Option option:selected').text(); 
        if (str == "Select...") {
            $('.BuyButton').hide();
        } else {
            $('.BuyButton').show();
        }
    });   
});
```

[A Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ABFar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".BuyButton").hide()
     $('.Option').change(function () {
         $(".BuyButton").css('display', ($('.Option:eq(0) option:selected').text() != "Select..." && $('.Option:eq(1) option:selected').text() != "Select..." && $('.Option:eq(2) option:selected').text() != "Select...") ? '' : 'none');
     });
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ABFar/3/)**

If you have an unknown number of selects, then you can use this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".BuyButton").hide()
     $('.Option').change(function () {
         var flag = false;
         $('.Option').each(function(){
             if($('option:selected',this).text()=="Select...") flag=true;;
         });
         $(".BuyButton").css('display',flag ? 'none':'');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version @sergio response.
It would be best if the default select option doesn't have a value.

```
<option selected="selected" value>Select...</option>
```

If that's not doable change the if statement line to

```
if ($(this).find(':selected').text() == 'Select...')
```

and that will work the same

```
$(function () {
    $(".BuyButton").hide();

    $('select').change(function () {
        var showButton = true;
        $('select').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                showButton = false;
            }
        });
        $(".BuyButton").toggle(showButton);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABFar/5/)

Here's what's going on.

When something is changed, assume we're going to how the button unless something goes wrong.
Look through all the selects.
If one of them doesn't have a val (`!` makes it a `not` statement) change flag to not show the button.

jQuery's `.toggle()` method can take a boolean value that tells it to hide or show.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('.Option').change(function() {
    $('.BuyButton').css('display', function(){
       var o = $('.Option').filter(function(){ return this.selectedIndex == 0 });
       return o.length ? 'none' : '';
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ABFar/8/)

Answer (score 0):

alot of answers have shown the flag method, and that is perfectly valid, but just to show a different way of doing it:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".BuyButton").hide()
     $('.Option').change(function () {
         $(".BuyButton").css('display', ($('.Option option:selected').map(function (index, domElement) {return $(domElement).text();}).get().indexOf("Select...") != -1 ? 'none' : ''));
     });
 });
```

this takes all option elements and maps them into an array, then checks if the array contains 'Select...'.